# HTACCESS: *.subdomain.domain.tld redir to subdomain.domain.tld/*

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

sorry for the vague question title.

But anyways,

I have here a subdomain which i wish to pass on wildcard sub-subdomains and make a proper htaccess redirect to a sub-folder (relative to the server root) equivalent to the wildcard value such that

```
*.subdomain.domain.tld will redirect to subdomain.domain.tld/*
```

where * = wildcard value

I hope you get my question. Can someone shed some light on this? I would appreciate it very much =)

Comment: I may have an answer if you're still looking, but it depends on how you have things set up. Does your subdomain point to a directory inside your server root (I assume yes, and if yes, do you know how that's defined?), and do you have full control over the server, or is it a shared host?

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule ^(.*).subdomain.domain.tld$ http://subdomain.domain.tld/$1 [R]`
That should do the trick.

The `[R]` tells the server that this is a redirect.
You can also use optional codes, say

```
[R=301] # Moved permanently
[R=302] # Moved temporarily
[R=403] # Forbidden
[R=404] # Not Found
[R=410] # Gone
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the subdomain's name with RewriteCond and then you can do the Redirect with RewriteRule, while the subdomain is saved in `%1`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.subdomain\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://subdomain.domain.tld/%1 [L,R=301]
```

If you want to redirect `*.subdomain.domain.tld/file.html` to `subdomain.domain.tld/*/file.html`, you can replace the RewriteRule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.tld/%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```